# How to track Facebook Share button in Google Analytics (analytics.js)

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-social-plugins, analytics.js

I am trying to track all the social interactions in my webpage using google analytics so that i can view them under Acquisition --> Social --> plugins.

Currently i am able to track the facebook like and send buttons but share button is not tracked. I could not find any specific codes for Share button. Most of the codes out in the web are mentioned to be for both Share/Send but shares are not getting tracked. I have provided the code below

```
        <html>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r; i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new    
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g; 
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('doc loaded');
});

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
                //Logged In Users
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status !== "unknown") { 
                ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Logged In');
            }
        });

        //Facebook Likes 
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
            var currentPage = $(document).attr('title');
            ga('send', {
                'hitType': 'social',
                'socialNetwork': 'Facebook',
                'socialAction': 'Like',
                'socialTarget': href,
                'page': currentPage,
                'hitCallback': function() {
                 alert('like done sending data');
  }

            });
        });

        //Facebook Unlikes
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
            var currentPage = $(document).attr('title');
            ga('send', {
                'hitType': 'social',
                'socialNetwork': 'Facebook',
                'socialAction': 'Unlike',
                'socialTarget': href,
                'page': currentPage,
                'hitCallback': function() {
    alert('unlike done sending data');
  }

            });
        });

        //Facebook Send/Share
        FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(href, widget) {


            var currentPage = $(document).attr('title');
            ga('send', {
                'hitType': 'social',
                'socialNetwork': 'Facebook',
                'socialAction': 'Send',
                'socialTarget': href,
                'page': currentPage,
                'hitCallback': function() {
    alert('send done sending data');
  }

            });
        });

        //Facebook Comments
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(href, widget) {
            var currentPage = $(document).attr('title');
            ga('send', {
                'hitType': 'social',
                'socialNetwork': 'Facebook',
                'socialAction': 'Comment',
                'socialTarget': href,
                'page': currentPage,
                'hitCallback': function() {
    alert('comment done sending data');
  }

            });
        });
      };
// Load Facebook SDK
    (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&  appId=xxxxxxxxxxxx";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>


      <p><a href="www.example.in" >Some Text </a></p>

      <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
      <fb:like></fb:like>

     <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://example.com"  data-layout="button_count"></div>

     <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com"></div>



      </body>
      </html>
```

I saw FB.event.subscribe method parameters from this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.4 but there is no specific parameter for share.
what am i doing wrong? Or is it not possible to track share button in facebook.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible to do with FB events. All possible events are in the docs you provided so if it's not there, you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to subscribe to share button events, but implementing a custom button with the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) provides a callback upon completion. You can push an event to Google Analytics in this callback.

Here's an example:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){
     //Google Analytics send here
});
```

You can also verify the share worked in the response by checking for `response.error_message`, although a note from the docs:

> Note that response.error_message will appear only if someone using your app has authenciated your app with Facebook Login.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.7 ) , there is still no event available with the share buttton...

Comment: You anwer is not complete enough. You should give a link, and even better a quote about what is written in the documentation.

Comment: According to the bug history for the old "message.send" event, facebook decided to no longer send an event for share actions. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1734301140155193/